# How to specify/enforce a specific node.js version to use in package.json?

Tags: node.js, npm

I am searching for a way to break the build, if a user is using a different node.js version as defined in the project.

Ideally to put some checks in grunt or bower or npm to stop, if a certain npm/node version is not used to run the current build.

Comment: And what's the problem to check node version and break build process?

Comment: Alexey, do you have an example of how to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I specify the required Node.js version in packages.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29349684/how-can-i-specify-the-required-node-js-version-in-packages-json)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the "engineStrict" property in your package.json

Check the docs for more information: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json

**Update on 23rd June 2019**

`"engineStrict"` property is removed in npm 3.0.0.

Reference : https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#enginestrict

Comment: ben, thx. engineStrict and engine solved my issue. Placed your answer as anwered

Comment: engineStrict is getting deprecated in the v3 of npm, do you have a new suggestion?

Comment: @cilap Since `engineStrict` has been deprecated, you should use you should use `--engine-strict=true` as an argument to `npm` in conjunction with the `engines` parameter in the `package.json`

Comment: You can also put `engine-strict=true` in your `.npmrc` file to enforce it for the project.

Answer (score 34):

Even though `engineStrict` is [deprecated](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/configuring-npm/package-json#enginestrict), you can still accomplish this behavior without needing to use an additional script to enforce a Node version in your project.

1. Add the `engines` property to your `package.json` file. For example:

   ```json
   {
     "name": "example",
     "version": "1.0.0",
     "engines": {
      "node": ">=14.0.0"
     }
   }
   ```
2. Create a `.npmrc` file in your project at the same level as your `package.json`.
3. In the newly created `.npmrc` file, add `engine-strict=true`.

   ```
   engine-strict=true
   ```

This will enforce the `engines` you've defined when the user runs `npm install`. I've created a simple example [on GitHub](https://github.com/blimmer/enforced-package-json-engines) for your reference.

Comment: For yarn berry (v2+) users, I recommend using the [yarn-plugin-engines](https://github.com/devoto13/yarn-plugin-engines) plugin. Also upvote https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/issues/1177 for native support.

Answer (score 9):

"engineStrict" has been removed and "engines" only works for dependencies. If you want to check Node's runtime version this can work for you:

You call this function in your server side code. It uses a regex to check Node's runtime version using [eremzeit's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36618449/3032209) It will throw an error if it's not using the appropriate version:

```
const checkNodeVersion = version => {
  const versionRegex = new RegExp(`^${version}\\..*`);
  const versionCorrect = process.versions.node.match(versionRegex);
  if (!versionCorrect) {
    throw Error(
      `Running on wrong Nodejs version. Please upgrade the node runtime to version ${version}`
    );
  }
};
```

usage:

```
checkNodeVersion(8)
```

Comment: I upvoted this answer because I needed a solution that would enforce even after installation. I needed to enforce Node 16 because Node 18 doesn't work at the moment. I wanted to prevent someone installed my project using 16 and then upgrading. I decided to write a shell script instead of using the JS code above.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `engines` property in the `package.json` file

For example, if you want to make sure that you have a minimum of node.js version 6.9 and a maximum of 6.10, then you can specify the following

```
package.json
{
    "name": "Foo",
    ....
    "engines": {
        "node": ">=6.9 <=6.10"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to enforce a specific version of npm, you might use: 
https://github.com/hansl/npm-enforce-version

If you want to enforce a version of node when executing you can read the version of node that is currently running by checking against:

`process.versions`

For more info: https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_versions

Comment: That npm-enforce-version package hasn't been updated since 2015. And since it tries to enforce the npm version to match its own package version, it can't work for any version of npm > 2.1.11.